# Fixed Rotation in Computer Graphics

Tags: c#, graphics

```
private void fixedRotate(int o,int i,double t,double x,double y)
    {
        translate(o, i, -x, -y);
        rotate(o, i, t);
        translate(o, i, x, y);
    }

private void rotate(int o,int i,double t)
    {
        double x1, y1;
        x1 = x[o, i];
        y1 = y[o, i];

        x[o, i] = x1 * Math.Cos(t) - y1 * Math.Sin(t);
        y[o, i] = x1 * Math.Sin(t) + y1 * Math.Cos(t);
    }
```

So from the translate() method the point goes to the (0,0) point. And then the rotation is done and the point is translated again. 
But in the rotate() method x1 and x2 will always be 0. So the x[o,i] y[o,i] both are 0. As I can understand this code should return the point to the same place. But the code is working fine. Please explain. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not included the translate method, please add so we have full picture. Also, in teh rotate method you have an x and y, declaration would be good to have.

Comment: you seem to have two conflicting definitions for x and y. never a good thing, imo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out. x and y in the method `fixedRotation()`means the center of the polygon. Which means if it's a square, the middle point of the square is translated to the center(0,0) point